# Appending to list in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am totally newbie in ruby, I want to create a list depending on the values of the stage, for this example. I have assigned the constant values. I am getting an empty array (NIL value).

```
PROD_WAVE1_STAGE = "prod-wave1"
PROD_WAVE2_STAGE = "prod-wave2"
PROD_WAVE3_STAGE = "prod-wave3"

def prod_dimensionality stage
whitelist = []

case stage
when 'prod-wave1'
    whitelist << 'NRT'
when 'PROD_WAVE2_STAGE'
    whitelist << 'SIN'
when 'PROD_WAVE3_STAGE'
    whitelist << 'DUB'
when 'PROD_WAVE4_STAGE' 
    whitelist << 'IAD'
end
end
prod_dimensionality(PROD_WAVE1_STAGE)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why not use the constants in the "case" too? And note all but the first one won't work correctly.

Comment: _I am not getting any return value._ **Every** method in Ruby returns something, so it is not possible to have a method call which does not return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the program as written is not wrong, it is a bit dangerous with respect to maintenance. Remember that a `case` statement returns the value of the last expression to be executed. In your case, this is something like `whitelist << 'SIN'`, and since `Array#<<` returns the array itself, you are returning `whitelist`, and this is exactly what you need.

But imagine that for reason of debugging, you would add additional statements - for instance a test print - to your program, so it looks like this:

```
def prod_dimensionality(stage)
  ...
  case ....
  end

  puts "whitelist=#{whitelist}" # Debugging output

end
```

In this case, the program would return the result of the `puts` statement, which will be `nil`. The caller would not see the whitelist anymore.

Therefore it is safer to write a return expression explicitly:

```
def prod_dimensionality(stage)
  ...
  case ....
  end

  whitelist # This is what will be returned   
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a hash that has the mappings in it. Then use that to decide what gets mapped in

```
stage_mappings = { 'prod-wave1' => 'NRT', ... }
whitelist << stage_mappings[stage]
whitelist.compact # In case there's some nils in there :D
```